# How to stencil texture paint seamlessly?

Tags: uv, texture-painting

I found it to be very difficult to stencil paint the texture seamlessly throughout the object , even when using seamless 2D image . Are there any technique to stencil paint the texture to the object so that the resulting texture on the object looks seamless ?

I don't mind using external 2D image editor program such as photoshop or gimp , as long as i achieve the goal.

[image]

Comment: The seamlessness of a 2D image only means that it can be tiled in a grid, because it has smooth (seamless) right-to-left and bottom-to-top transitions.

Comment: yeah i know , i thought by using seamless 2D image that i made using photoshop i could paint it side by side and make it look seamless , turns out i was wrong , that's why i asked this question

Answer (score 1):

If you have modeled the apple using reference images showing each side, you can simply stencil the texture on it in the corresponding viewpoints (front, left, top, etc).

Start with an aligned view like *View > Viewpoint > Front* (<kbd>Numpad 1</kbd>) and paint on it. Paint mainly in the center of the apple because there will be massive stretching at the edges of the object.

Then switch to the next point of view (e.g. *View > Viewpoint > Right* (<kbd>Numpad 3</kbd>)) and use the corresponding image (part) for the stencil. Repeat the steps for all visible sides of the apple.

At the edges, a seamless transition results if you focus on the center for each side.

[image: clone apples]

Clone apples. This is the same apple, three times.

**Addendum**

Looks like you followed [this tutorial](https://youtu.be/lmbAs9jE1vI). The used images seem to have a perspective, lens distortion, or are photoshopped, or are not turned by exactly 90°. I'm not sure. But something doesn't look right.

[image: stencil image]
<sup>Used images for the stencil / screenshot from the video</sup>

Compare the second image in the first row (image 2-1, "left"), and the image 1-2, ("front"), and 2-2 ("right"). On all three images, you can see the bright yellow area. But in the images of the two side views, the spot should only be visible as a very small strip, shouldn't it?

In consequence, you need to adjust it a bit. Begin with the "front" view and adjust the sides a bit. Scale them up and/or move them a bit in the front direction so that the yellow area overlaps appropriately. Do the same for the "back" image (1-1) in direction of the back. If you let the pattern match, it will look good.

As you see, you can barely see the yellow area from the side:

[image: half turnaround]
<sup>180° turnaround - right - front - left view</sup>

Comment: i tried this , but there is still seams on the edge of the object even when i paint mainly on the center , and when i try to remove the seams by brushing on it , the seams become bigger instead of going away

Comment: I've updated the answer. In the example, I've used a screenshot of the textures from the video to paint my model. It works :D  Have you tried to match the pattern? Lower the brush strength a bit (0.7) for the edges and use full strength in the center only.